# Pointers vs. References in C++ function arguments

Tags: c++, pointers

I was wondering how to make a function alter two variables (the return and another one) and I stumbled upon calling the function with an '&' before the parameter (which I understand to mean the address of the parameter) then throughout your function, referencing it with the '*' sign (which I guess is a "dereference" and means it alters the object at the address).

Anyways, this was all going fine, then a friend said you can just call the function with the variable directly, refer to the variable with an & before it in the header, and treat it normally throughout the function. This seems way easier, so why isn't there more about it on the web? Is one style more correct than the other?

```
void foo(int &junk)  //The way the friend said
{
    junk++;
}

void oof(int *junk) //what I found, and what the internet seems full of
{
    (*junk)++;
}

int main ()
{
    int junk=1;
    std::cout << junk << "\n";
    foo(junk);
    std::cout << junk << "\n";
    oof(&junk);
    std::cout << junk;
}
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

So everything works fine, I'd assume.

Comment: using the & in the parameter name creates a "reference variable".  The classic pointer approach `void oof(int *junk)` is the only way you can do something like this in C.  Many people prefer using pointers for variables when you intend to change them because it makes it more obvious to the caller that you intend to modify the variable.  The reference variable approach is more commonly used with const parameters such as `void(const int & junk)` meaning the argument won't be modified.

Comment: The OP indicated that they would like [multiple return values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624779/returning-multiple-data-items-from-a-function-in-c-or-c), which is not mentioned in the current answers or proposed duplicate. For that, consider something like returning a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and continuing to accept arguments as you typically would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first approach is called "passing by reference"; the second approach is called "passing by pointer". In the first case, dereference is implicit (no asterisk); in the second case, dereference is explicit.

The biggest difference between the two approaches is that when you pass by pointer, you can pass "nothing" (i.e. a null pointer). When you pass by reference, it is not possible to legally pass a reference to nothing: it should be a reference to some variable, an array element, a field of a class or a structure, etc.

When you need to return a value and modify a variable, passing by reference is more appropriate, because the variable that you need to modify always exists. Passing by pointer becomes more appropriate in situations when you traverse a dynamic data structure connected by pointers, when parts of that data structure may or may not exist.

Comment: This (accepted) answer is opposite to the higher voted answer below. Also, I would argue that "junk" is more implicit than "*junk".

Comment: A small note, just to avoid confusions to anyone reading this answer: the '* example' is passing by pointer, the '& one' is passing by reference. As noted by so860, this looks like it is inverted, but that's probably because the title of the question is "pointer vs reference" but the example puts the reference first.

Comment: @JACH Thank you very much for the commend. I edited to reverse the "first" and "second".

Answer (score 4):

The you first function `foo`, you are passing by reference :

> When a variable is passed by reference we are not passing a copy of its value, but we are somehow passing the variable itself to the function and any modification that we do to the local variables will have an effect in their counterpart variables passed as arguments in the call to the function.

An example of passing by reference :

[image: Passing by reference]

In your second example `oof`, you are passing a pointer to the variable.

If you want to know the different between both example, I suggest you to read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57492/1394283

**But, When you should use `references` and when you should use `pointer` ?**

I will say use `references` whenever you can, use `pointers` whenever you must.

> The reason is that pointers makes things harder to follow/read, less safe and far more dangerous manipulations than any other constructs.

This post explains it very well : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058373/1394283